# Use setInterval conditionally

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval

Is it possible that if the value of `$new` is changed then the `var updateChart()` function will reload again and then again it goes to the `var check()` function and again have the same condition on it?

```
var updateInterval = 3000;
  var updateChart = function() {
      var check = function() {
        if(<?php echo $new; ?>).change(function(){
          setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, 1000);
        });
      }
    dps.push(<?php echo $str; ?>);
    chart.render();   
};
```

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense to me: you should know that the PHP parts are executed and echo'd out as soon as the page is created, so the `$new` element will never be updated via PHP. The `if().change()` block will immediately be fired because it will trigger the change event and then execute the inner code. You are defining a function called `check()` but in your posted code you are not executing it.

Comment: yeah right i am getting the problem in `.change()` function but for that how can I use this statement that when the `$new` value is change which means num_rows increased only then the UpdateChart function will execute.

Comment: I am still not sure if I got you correctly but I'll give you an answer that hopefully fits.

Comment: Actually i want to push the $str value in the `var dps` only when I add the the row in my database. So i just want to setinterval on `$new` variable so that when the `$new Variable` change only the the push function execute only once. 
I hope now i am Clear to you

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to update a chart as soon as some value has been written on the server-side, right? As mentioned in my comment, using PHP statements in your JS block will not work as the PHP code will be run on page load and won't change afterwards. Instead, you should use a two-step approach:

- Use a recurring AJAX call to poll for changes
- Create a PHP page that reports changes

---

**JS code (using [Jquery](https://jquery.com/)):**

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax('change-listener.php', {
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.changed) {
        for(var i in data.newValue) {
          dps.push(data.newValue[i]);
        }
        chart.render();
      }
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

Check which rows have been written in a given time span (assuming your table that you right records into has a timestamp) and return the corresponding values via JSON to the JS script:

**PHP code:**

```
$query= 'SELECT strValue FROM [YOURTABLE] WHERE created > DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 3 SECOND)';

$data= array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) { 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        $data['changed']= TRUE;
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            $data['newValues'][]= $obj->strValue;
        } 
    } else {
        $data['changed']= FALSE;
    }
} 
$result->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($data);
```

---

An alternate way would be to store the newly created values inside the user's session:

**PHP Code, part 1** (inside the script that handles storing of new values):

```
session_start();    
$_SESSION['newValues'][]= $str;
```

**PHP Code, part 2** (instead of polling the database, poll the session):

```
session_start();  
if (isset($_SESSION['newValues'])) {
  $data['changed']= TRUE;
  $data['newValues']) $_SESSION['newValues'];
  unset($_SESSION['newValues'];
} else {
  $data['changed']= FALSE;
}
```

The second approach is a pure single-user scenario: as soon as the PHP script polls for changes, changes are returned once and then the list of changes is reset to never return the same values twice.

Comment: Thanks For Giving So well Answer i Really Appreciate you for this. but now the Problem is i am making graphs for live basket ball match for which i render the time format as  

`[{"x":new Date(0000,00,00,00,00,30),"y":2},`

and if i conver this in EncodeJson then it renders 

`[{"x":"new Date(0000,00,00,00,00,30)","y":2},`

which the canvas JS dont Pick the format so i Use `preg_replace` to remove double quotes and then i again tried to render chart

Comment: I know its kinda difficult i wish could we do TeamViewer so that i could able to show you what i am really suffering from. If we could do TeamViewer Kindly Inform me.

Comment: Sorry, I currently haven't TeamViewer installed. You seem to be mixing languages again and you should never pass along anything as string that should be converted on the receiving side with means like `eval()`, that will lead to problems at some point. Instead create the date on the server-side (i.e. `$date= new Date();`) and pass that along with your JSON data (`print json_encode(array('x' => $date, 'y'  => 2));`).